# How to get the file extension in Jenkins Pipeline

Tags: linux, bash, jenkins, devops

Using `bash` I can get the file extension by simply:

```
FILE_BASENAME="abcd.001.xyz.txt"
FILE_EXTENSION="${FILE_BASENAME##*.}"
echo $FILE_EXTENSION
```

I can also get the same result using a bit different syntax:

```
FILE_BASENAME="abcd.001.xyz.txt"
RESULT=$(echo "${FILE_BASENAME##*.}")
echo $FILE_EXTENSION
```

Regardless what way is used the both approaches produce a string `txt`.

Unfortunately the same syntax in Jenkins pipeline results to an empty string:

```
FILE_EXTENSION = sh(script: '$(echo "${FILE_BASENAME##*.}")', returnStdout: true).trim()
```

I have also tried a variation of this command with

```
FILE_EXTENSION = sh(script: 'echo $(echo "${FILE_BASENAME##*.}")', returnStdout: true).trim()
```

which doesn't work as well.

How to get the file extension in Jenkins?

Comment: Why is this tagged [tag:bash]?  Prefix-removal expansion is a [standard shell feature](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_06_02).

Answer (score 0):

Designed to support the three characters file extension:

```
  FILE_BASENAME="abcd.001.xyz.txt"
  FILE_NAME = FILE_BASENAME.replaceAll(".[a-zA-Z]{3}\$", "")
  FILE_EXT = FILE_BASENAME.replaceAll(FILE_NAME, "")
  echo ("FILE_NAME: ${FILE_NAME} FILE_EXT: ${FILE_EXT}")
```

Output:

```
FILE_NAME: abcd.001.xyz FILE_EXT: .txt
```